# Apache Ignite RPM Repo

Tags: ignite, apacheignite

the Apache Ignite documentation on https://ignite.apache.org/docs/latest/installation/deb-rpm points to https://www.apache.org/dist/ignite/rpm (redirects to) https://apache.jfrog.io/ui/native/ignite-rpm/ as the official RPM repository.

When I create a yum repository file pointing to the base url baseurl=https://apache.jfrog.io/artifactory/ignite-rpm/ yum will only find versions up to 2.10, but not the newer versions. The newer versions are contained in a subfolder "apache-ignite" (https://apache.jfrog.io/ui/native/ignite-rpm/apache-ignite/). The files in that subfolder don't seem to be referenced by the repodata and cannot be found via yum. So the repository seems to be in an invalid state. Is this not maintained, or why does it look like that?

Regards,
Sven

I would like to be able to install Ignite versions 2.13 and 2.14 via RPM repository instead of having to download the RPMs for installation myself.

Comment: I guess that there might be some naming changes that were not handled properly. Please consider to create a Jira ticket for that.